# Opening certain OS X preference panes programmatically in El Capitan

Tags: macos, url-scheme, system-preferences

In Yosemite it is possible to open System Preferences on a specific pane and tab by opening a URL like `x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts` or `x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preferences.extensions?Share_Menu`.

However this no longer works in El Capitan, instead opening just the normal System Preferences. Is there any way to achieve this functionality in El Capitan?

**Note:** Oddly enough the URL `x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Accessibility` does still work in El Capitan.

Comment: x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Accessibility didn't work on my MacBook with El C. 10.11.6.

Comment: It seems Apple must have patched it in one of the recent updates then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I've come up with is to execute AppleScript to select the desired pane, however this is not able to select a control within that pane, e.g. the "Share Menu" section of the "Extensions" preferences pane.

```
NSString *script = @"tell application \"System Preferences\"\n\tset the current pane to pane \"com.apple.preferences.extensions\"\n\tactivate\nend tell";
NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:script];
[appleScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
```